# is subset of probability measures with finite second moment a Borel set?

Tags: general-topology, probability-theory

We know that the space of the probability measures on $\mathbb{R}^n$ endowed with the topology of weak convergence is a Borel space.

My question is that the subset of those that have finite second moment a Borel subset?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, of course.  Write the finiteness in terms of integrals of bounded continuous functions: there exists $N$ such that for all $n$, ...

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But would you please elaborate more? I didn't go far in topology or function analysis yet. Thank you very much!